# Mac OS X-like application launching for Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: launcher, services, dock

Once an application is first launched in OS X from the dock, it stays open in the background, even after you close all open windows for that application. For example, if I open Google Chrome from the dock and start a session with 3 windows, then close all of those windows when finished with them, the Chrome icon will retain the small dot under its dock icon signifying that it is still 'open in the background'. This makes opening further windows for that application almost instant, rather than having to reload the application every time to create a new window. I am wondering if it is possible to implement this feature in a Linux environment, as I have not found a way to do so.

Note that I am only talking about the application launching mechanism, I am aware of Docky and other programs that simulate the OS X dock, but I have not yet came across a way to make Linux exhibit this preloading behaviour.

Thank you

Comment: What if you want to close a program to free up some resources? How do you do this in OSX?

Comment: You can right click on the dock icon to fully 'Quit' the app, or press Cmd-Q.

Answer (score 1):

*Hi there. I'm not sure if this specifically addresses your dock question, but I have found some information about the pre-loading feature that you are talking about.*

Have you taken a look at **Preload**? It fits your requirements and works in Ubuntu as well.

> Preload is considered to be read-ahead daemon application as it
>   analyzes the applications which user runs, and on the basis of this
>   analysis it predicts which applications user can run next time and
>   launches these applications in RAM. Its daemon keeps running in
>   background all the time and saves the required information about the
>   applications you are running so that it may load them quickly next
>   time.

**Here's the link to where I got the above quote and for more information on Preload, including how to install it:** http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/speed-up-applications-load-time-with-preload-in-ubuntu-linux/